# dummy variable columns based on strings from other columns

Tags: r, function, dplyr, dummy-variable

I have a database with patient id number and the treatment they recived. I would like to have a dummy column for every different INDIVIDUAL treatment (ie, as in did the patient recieve treatment A,B,C,D).

This is way simplified because I have over 20 treatments and thousands of patients, and I can't figure out a simple way to do so.

```
example <- data.frame(id_number = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                      treatment = c("A", "A+B+C+D", "C+B", "B+A", "C"))
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
desired_result <- data.frame(id_number = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                             treatment = c("A", "A+B+C+D", "C+B", "B+A","C"),
                             A=c(1,1,0,1,0), 
                             B=c(0,1,1,1,0),
                             C=c(0,1,1,0,1),
                             D=c(0,1,0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
example %>%
 mutate(treatment2 = strsplit(treatment, "+", fixed = TRUE)) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 spread(treatment2, treatment2) %>%
 mutate_at(vars(-id_number, -treatment), ~ (!is.na(.)) * 1)

  id_number treatment A B C D
1         0         A 1 0 0 0
2         1   A+B+C+D 1 1 1 1
3         2       C+B 0 1 1 0
4         3       B+A 1 1 0 0
5         4         C 0 0 1 0
```

Or:

```
example %>%
 mutate(treatment2 = strsplit(treatment, "+", fixed = TRUE)) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 mutate(val = 1) %>%
 spread(treatment2, val, fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

A `base` version:

```
example["A"] <- as.numeric(grepl("A", example[,"treatment"]))
example["B"] <- as.numeric(grepl("B", example[,"treatment"]))
example["C"] <- as.numeric(grepl("C", example[,"treatment"]))
example["D"] <- as.numeric(grepl("D", example[,"treatment"]))

example

  id_number treatment A B C D
1         0         A 1 0 0 0
2         1   A+B+C+D 1 1 1 1
3         2       C+B 0 1 1 0
4         3       B+A 1 1 0 0
5         4         C 0 0 1 0
```

The `grepl` function tests the presence of each pattern in each row, and `as.numeric` changes the logical TRUE/FALSE to 1/0